# How to compile angular 2 elements from a json file with html content?

Tags: html, json, angular, angular2-directives

I am working on a project where I am loading data to a nestable list view from a json file since I want the data to be dynamically loaded from an API.

```
{
    "demo1": [{
            "id": 1,
            "content": "<div> General </div>"

        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "content": " Security ",
            "children" :[{
                    "id":5,
                    "content" : "Password"
            },
            {
                    "id":6,
                    "content" : "System Idle"
            },
            {
                    "id":7,
                    "content" : "Login"
            }]

        },
        {
             "id": 8,
            "content": " Evaluations "

        },

        {
            "id" :9,
            "content" : "Reports"
        }


    ],
    "Password": [
       {
                    "id": 11,
                    "content": "Expiry Interval"},
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "content": " Expire Password Now  <input  class =\"pull-right\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox-inline\">"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "content": " Days to Password Expiry <div _ngcontent-xtu-75=\"\" class=\"pull-right\" style=\"width : 200px\"><div _ngcontent-xtu-75=\"\" ng-reflect-sa-jqui-slider=\"[object Object]\" class=\"ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content\"><span tabindex=\"0\" class=\"ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default\" style=\"left: 0%;\"></span></div></div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "content": "<div> Days to expire email reminder link  <on-off-switch></on-off-switch></div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "content": "<div class=\"settings-element clearfix\"><p class=\"pull-left\">New password should not be same as old password</p><div class=\"pull-right\"><on-off-switch></on-off-switch></div></div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "content": " Allow user to change password <div class=\"pull-right onoffswitch-container\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-title\"><ng-content></ng-content><\/span><span class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" [(ngModel=\"value\" [checked]=\"value\"(ngModelChange)=\"onChange()\" id=\"{{widgetId}}\"/> <label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" htmlFor=\"{{widgetId}}\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" data-swchon-text=\"ON\"data-swchoff-text=\"OFF\"></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"><\/span><\/label><\/span><\/div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "content": " Force user to change password after first login <div class=\"pull-right onoffswitch-container\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-title\"><ng-content></ng-content><\/span><span class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" [(ngModel=\"value\" [checked]=\"value\"(ngModelChange)=\"onChange()\" id=\"{{widgetId}}\"/> <label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" htmlFor=\"{{widgetId}}\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" data-swchon-text=\"ON\"data-swchoff-text=\"OFF\"></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"><\/span><\/label><\/span><\/div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "content": " Force user to enter new password twice <div class=\"pull-right onoffswitch-container\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-title\"><ng-content></ng-content><\/span><span class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" [(ngModel=\"value\" [checked]=\"value\"(ngModelChange)=\"onChange()\" id=\"{{widgetId}}\"/> <label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" htmlFor=\"{{widgetId}}\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" data-swchon-text=\"ON\"data-swchoff-text=\"OFF\"></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"><\/span><\/label><\/span><\/div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "content": " Force password rules <div class=\"pull-right onoffswitch-container\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-title\"><ng-content></ng-content><\/span><span class=\"onoffswitch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" [(ngModel=\"value\" [checked]=\"value\"(ngModelChange)=\"onChange()\" id=\"{{widgetId}}\"/> <label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" htmlFor=\"{{widgetId}}\"><span class=\"onoffswitch-inner\" data-swchon-text=\"ON\"data-swchoff-text=\"OFF\"></span><span class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"><\/span><\/label><\/span><\/div>"
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "content": " Maximum length "
                },
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "content": " Minimum length "
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "content": " Must contain Uppercase characters (A-Z)"
                },
                {
                    "id": 23,
                    "content": " Must contain Digits (0-9) "
                },
                {
                    "id": 24,
                    "content": " Must contain Special characters "
                },
                {
                    "id": 25,
                    "content": " Apply Password rules to role "
                },
                {
                    "id": 26,
                    "content": " Maintain history of password validation "
                },
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "content": " Number of passwords to maintain in history "
                }
            ],
     "Login": [{
            "id": 33,
            "content": " Restrict number of failed passcode attempts "
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "content": " Maximum failed passcode attempts "
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "content": " Password retry attempt time limit "
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "content": " Account lockout threshold "

        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "content": " Allow lockout threshold "
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "content": " Allow user to login to multiple devices "
        }
    ],
    "Reports" : [{
            "id": 41,
            "content" : "Risk Threshold"
    }],
    "General" : [{
        "id" : 42,
        "content" : "Logo"
        },
        {
         "id" : 43,
         "content" :  "Title to appear in place of company name"  
        },
        {
          "id" : 44,
          "content" : "Default Language " 
        },
        {
           "id" : 45,
           "content" : "Allow Notfications to be sent out automatically" 
        },
        {
            "id": 46,
            "content" : "Timezone"
        }

    ],
    "System Idle" :[{
        "id" : 47,
        "content" : "Logout user after x minutes if idle"
    }],
      "Evaluations": [{
            "id":48,
            "content" :"No of days for Due Date"
            },
            {
             "id" : "49",
             "content" : "Allow ducplicate "
            },
            {
             "id" : "50",
             "content" : "Allow custom choice sets "
            }
 ]
}
```

I have HTML5 elements as a string in the json file. But when I append angular selectors such as  in the json file, the elements does not get rendered in the view.

Here is my component.ts file code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {JsonApiService} from "../../shared/api/json-api.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'sa-settings',
  templateUrl: 'new.settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['new.settings.component.css']
})
export class NewSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

 public demo1: any;

 public totalData: any;

 public demo2: any;

 public nestable2DemoOutput: any;


  public demo3: any;
  public nestableOutput: any;
  public demoString:string;


  constructor(private jsonApiService:JsonApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.jsonApiService.fetch('/ui-examples/settings-list.json').subscribe(data=> {
      this.demo1 = data.demo1; 
      this.demo3 = data.demo3;
      this.totalData = data;
    })
  }


  public onChange(payload){
    this.nestableOutput = payload
  }


  public onClick(event:any,string:string){

  }

  public showSelected(event){
        this.demo2 = [];
        while(document.getElementById("settings").firstChild.firstChild) {
           document.getElementById("settings").firstChild.removeChild(document.getElementById("settings").firstChild.firstChild);
        }
        this.demoString = event.target.innerText;
        this.demo2 = this.totalData[event.target.innerText];
    }
}
```

Here is my component.html file code :

```
<div id="content">


    <div class="row">
        <sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Administration', 'Application Settings']" icon="wrench" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></sa-big-breadcrumbs>

    </div>

    <!--
      The ID "widget-grid" will start to initialize all widgets below
      You do not need to use widgets if you dont want to. Simply remove
      the <section></section> and you can use wells or panels instead
      -->
    <!-- widget grid -->
    <sa-widgets-grid>
        <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
            <article class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
                <sa-widget [colorbutton]="false" [editbutton]="false" [collapsed]="false" [deletebutton]="false" [fullscreenbutton]="false" color="darken">

                    <header>
                        <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> </span>

                        <h2>Settings</h2>
                    </header>
                    <!-- widget div-->
                    <div>
                        <!-- widget content -->
                        <div class="widget-body">
                            <!-- this is what the user will see -->
                            <div class="widget-body" id="newTemplate">
                                <sa-setting
                                (click)="showSelected($event)"
                                [items]="demo1" 
                                (change)="onChange($event)" 
                                [options]="{ group: 2 }">
                                </sa-setting>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end widget content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end widget div -->
                </sa-widget>
                <!-- end widget -->
            </article>
            <!-- WIDGET END -->
            <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
            <article class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
                <sa-widget [colorbutton]="false" [editbutton]="false" [deletebutton]="false" [fullscreenbutton]="false" color="darken">
                    <!-- widget options:
              usage: <sa-widget id="wid-id-0" [editbutton]="false">
              [colorbutton]="false"
              [editbutton]="false"
              [togglebutton]="false"
              [deletebutton]="false"
              [fullscreenbutton]="false"
              [custombutton]="false"
              [collapsed]="true"
              [sortable]="false"
          -->
                    <header>
                        <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i> </span>
                        <h2 class="font-md">{{demoString}}</h2>
                    </header>
                    <!-- widget div-->
                    <div>
                        <!-- widget content -->

                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <sa-setting id="settings" 
                                [items]="demo2" 
                                (change)="onChange($event)" 
                                [options]="{ group: 2 }">
                                </sa-setting>
                            </div>
                        <!-- end widget content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end widget div -->
                </sa-widget>
                <!-- end widget -->


            </article>
            <!-- WIDGET END -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
        <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- a blank row to get started -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- your contents here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
    </sa-widgets-grid>
    <!-- end widget grid -->
</div>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: This won't work. Code in showSelected() has nothing to do with angular. You cannot just add some subtree to DOM manually and hope that angular will figure out by itself what it has to do about it. And even if we put that aside, if you manually add something to DOM then it is your responsibility to make it "alive" - connect event handlers, change element properties etc. Angular will know nothing about your additions to the DOM and what to do with them. Whole point of angular is about not building DOM directly.

Comment: Correct approach would be to write component(s) that would render on the client all the things that you want, not reading them from server. In angular application you should read from server only raw data, not html markup.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderLeonov